Can I import CSV data into localStorage as an ARRAY not an OBJECT?
The following code is suppose to import data into localStorage from a CSV file. The goal is that is should replace / update any existing localStorage data. I am using FileReader to import and was tryign to use JSON.stringify  to save it to localStorage.
const fileInput = document.getElementById('csv');

const readFile = () => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("entry_list", JSON.stringify(reader.result));
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput.files[0]);
};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);

I believe the issues is that is it trying to import this as an OBJECT rather than an ARRAY. How do I approach this problem or fix this issue?
UPDATE:
Thanks to the answer posted by zzzggghhh below, I was able to get this 90% resolved. The only issue remaining is that one of the array elements, which is a number has to be a float. So the splitting method should somehow account for this. Is it even possible?
This is what is being imported:

I need it to be imported like this (without quotes on the float):


what is the issue or problem from your code?

This is what I am asking help for. The import is not importing the data correctly. It seem to be creating an OBJECT from the CSV import instead of an ARRAY. Also, it is not bringing in any data. The CSV file has data inside but it is not being imported.

This is what I have come up with. It seems to work. Thanks to all who helped.
const fileInput = document.getElementById('csv');

const update = async () => {
    const [header, ...rows] = (await fileInput.files[0].text()).trim().split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => line.split(','));
    const records = rows.map(row => {
        // Assuming the last column is a float
        const floatValue = parseFloat(row[row.length - 1]);
        // Remove the last element (float value) from the row
        const fields = row.slice(0, -1);
        // Create the record object with fields and float value
        const record = fields.reduce((record, field, i) => Object.assign(record, { [header[i]]: field }), {});
        // Add the float value to the record
        record[header[header.length - 1]] = floatValue;
        return record;
    });
    // Save data to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("entry_list", JSON.stringify(records));
};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', update);


CSV is plaintext, importing an array buffer is for binary data/files. You can just use the fetch API to read all of the text and then parse it into objects from CSV using a module perhaps:
const fileInput = document.getElementById('csv')

const update = async () => {
    const [header, ... rows] = (await fileInput.files[0].text()).trim().split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => line.split(','))
    const records = rows.map(row => row.reduce((record, field, i) => Object.assign(record, {[header[i]]: field}), {}))
    localStorage.setItem("entry_list", JSON.stringify(records))
}

fileInput.addEventListener('change', update) 


This does not properly parse the CSV file. (And no, splitting by comma wouldn't be enough either, because you can have quoted fields, you can also have quoted fields spanning multiple lines, and you can have escaped quotes within quoted fields.) - This is why I suggested using an existing library for this.

Neither does yours, it's up to him what 3rd party CSV package he wants to use.

Mine doesn't even try, as I know it would be wrong. But your answer goes half-way, and it does so in the wrong direction. Also you can't fetch a File object. Try it yourself.

You actually can fetch a file.

See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/ytcksnbL/ - you get some HTML garbage output because end up fetching the 404 page by trying to fetch data from the URL [object%20File].

Cool, he didn't post any HTML so I assumed it was Node server code

Thank you zzzggghhh, it is getting me very close to success. I think I am learning what is going on here. There seems to be one small issues that if giving me problems, I think it has to do with how it is being split and the output need to be an array or arrays... This is what I get using your solution: '["type,title,amount","expense,Rent,1900","expense,Hydro,100"]' What I need it this: '[{"type,title,amount"},{"expense,Rent,1900"},{"expense,Hydro,100"]}' I may have confused my terminology, I think we call this an array of array?

It might be hard to understand, but I edited it with something should work for your case. It would be a better idea to use an existing package like csv-parse and import it into a real web app project. You can learn about Node.js and Express.js, that's a good place to start with making a web app.

zzzggghhh, Thank you again for this information and as soon as I finish this project, I will look into Node and Express. The code you have provided works fine except for the numbers, which I believe need to be an float (is it possible?). I am not so good at backwards engineering your code but using the console I find that this is what I get:
0: {type: 'expense', title: 'Rent', amount: '1900'} where as I need this:
0: {type: 'expense', title: 'Rent', amount: 1900} to remove the quotes from the number, I am not ungrateful, I am learning a lot, I wish I can buy a user a coffee from this site.

@user3146788 CSV doesn't have data types so you can't tell a string 123 apart from a number 123. If you know a certain column always has numbers though, then you can map the values to numbers at the end. Or, you could implement a heuristic in which you use a regex like -?\d+(\.\d+)? to detect things that look like a number and then convert those to actual numbers.

Hey CherryDT, well I did not have the words to describe it like you have but this was my thought. A way to target the last element (key:amount. value:float) of each row as it it will always be the float. I admit I don't know quite how yet I think array.row[2]. Or to chop up the array and reassemble it, which I now know is regex. I am goign to have to research these. I would love to build upon the exiting code provided by zzzhhhggg because I pretty much understand what is going on there. I need that number as a float because the rest of the app, does a few math calculations which are now broke.

The issue is that you try to use JSON.stringify on an ArrayBuffer object. An ArrayBuffer does not have any enumerable object properties and hence becomes just {} when stringified.
Either turn it into a regular array using JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Uint8Array(reader.result))) so you get every byte in the file as a number, or - my recommendation, since it's easier to turn into a file again and smaller to store - don't read it as ArrayBuffer in the first place but as data URI (which will use base64-encoding) by replacing readAsArrayBuffer with readAsDataURL.
However, based on your comments, I am now quite sure that you would like to parse the CSV contents as well, instead of just storing the file. In this case take a look at one of the many CSV parsing packages out there, such as csv-parse.
Here is an example how to use it:


const fileInput = document.getElementById('csv');

const readFile = () => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload = () => {
    const csvData = csv_parse_sync.parse(reader.result, { columns: true });
    // Commented out because sandboxed demo cannot access localStorage
    //localStorage.setItem("entry_list", JSON.stringify(csvData));
    
    // For demo purposes, show would normally get stored
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(csvData);
  }
  reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);
};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/csv-parse@5.5.5/dist/umd/sync.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="csv">

<pre id="output"></pre>



Instead of a CDN like I used here, you would normally copy the relevant file from the package onto your server (or install the package there, if you can) and reference the file this way.

Yes, I hope I did not confuse. I do not want to store it as a file. I already have the data in a CSV file. That part of my code, not shown here, works perfectly. I need to read in the data in the CSV and put into localStorage (updating / replacing) what is already there. I hope this makes sense. Thank you

Yes but in what way? The CSV file just contains bytes. It's up to you to decide how they should be interpreted. My assumption is that you want to parse CSV into an array of objects based on column names, which is where packages like csv-parse can help you, but you didn't really say that. You might as well want to store an array of arrays of cells or simply text parsed as some encoding like UTF-8. (Or raw bytes, as I originally thought.)

Ok, I have to admit, I am new so it is possible I don't fully know "what to say". I currently have an array of objects in local storage. All I want to do is replace or update that data with the data which is stored in the CSV.  I will follow your advice and seek more information on csv-parse although it is for Node.JS which I am not using. Is there not an approach using vanilla JS?

Not sure if this will help but, I have tried this:localStorage.setItem("entry_list", JSON.stringify(Array.from(reader.result))); but the array is still empty in localStorage but ther are no errors

No, csv-parse is also for the browser. To quote the page I linked: Multiple distributions: Node.js, Web, ECMAScript modules and CommonJS. It's all explained on their website.

Also, in regards to what you last tried, that can't work either because you forgot the intermediate conversion to new Uint8Array as I showed in my answer above. But I am now quite sure that you don't need to the raw contents of the file anyway.

The first step in the instructions for the csv-parse is to: Run npm install csv to install the full CSV module or run npm install csv-parse if you are only interested by the CSV parser. I don't have Node.JS and this need to be client side solution. I appreciate this help but I need a practical example. I guess I need to hire someone to help me find a solution. I really did not think is was so difficult to get a practical example or demo from this community I am going down a path that is beyond my skill set apparently. Thanks...

Usually, your frontend nowadays also uses node for being built. At the end you get client-side code only, but the build process uses node packages, and that's why the first explanation uses npm, but you don't have to go this route. You can use the provided browser IIFE distribution as well, the website also shows this as an example. I'm going to add it in more detail to my answer, now that I'm quite sure I understand what you need.

I added a concrete example.
